# What's more important, sensitivity, resolution or uncertainty when talking sensors?

Tags: sensor, device-characteristics

If you had to choose just one characteristic, what would you predominate among this static characteristics? Sensitivity, resolution or uncertainty.

Comment: Neither. It always depends on your application what you need. Also "uncertainty" isn't really the term you're looking for, probably you mean "accuracy".

Comment: You need to "qualify" your answer. What Neil says. Application can greatly affect parameter importance.

Answer (score 5):

The important characteristics aren't in your list.

Dynamic range, or signal to noise ratio, is the nearest to encompassing all of your criteria and more, depending on exactly how it's defined.

If you play about with the definition at the low end, then you can trade off accuracy, resolution, stability, noise, and sensitivity. If your application measures over short intervals, then you may not need to include stability in your list of sources of 'noise', and go flat-out for resolution. If it measures over months, then good resolution may be useless without long term stability.

If you play about with the definition at the high end, then you can trade off linearity, full scale, overload and damage level.

You'll often find that a sensor with a limited dynamic range can be made more usable for a given application by shifting its operating level with an amplifier or attenuator placed in front of it. This will trade off its maximum and minimum usable signal levels, but the dynamic range will stay the same (until the amplifier limits the high signal end or the attenuator drops the signal into thermal noise).

Generally, comparing a cheap sensor, and a more expensive professional sensor, it's almost always the case that the professional sensor has more dynamic range.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you need to ponder where resides the INFORMATION of your system, here being the SENSOR.

Being patient and waiting (milliseconds, many milliseconds) as low_pass_filtering removes random noise, power supply trash, and cellphone interference, is one method.

If the code_spreading actions are very low, then lots of amplification will help you.

Or a high_resolution ADC may be the simple approach.

But YOU have to decide where is the information.

For example, in a diffusion furnace in a silicon_wafer doping facility, the temperature of the wafers is crucial to control how DEEP the gaseous atoms will be absorbed into the silicon surface.

You need to measure the temperature very accurately, and very consistently, so the sweet_spot temperature for usefully_profiled FET and Bipolar junctions is repeatable. Without consistency, you do not have any yields. And you go broke.

Measuring at Room Temperature is not important.

And your temperature readings may even be WRONG, as long as consistent (that REPEATABILITY that I mentioned).

You have to work thru the requirements for your entire system, and decide where the INFORMATION resides.